# Better way to call new Audio();

Tags: javascript, audio

I am making game in browser and use sound effects for example shot, explosion and for every generated instance of classes there is also creating new Audio object which is eating memory so much and app is crashing after 2/3 minutes thats mean is getting very slow. Is any better way to do this? Maybe creating new Audio() in another place but just once and call it when need, not every time when generating new enemy, bullet etc.

For example:

```
class Bullet extends Common {
    constructor() {

    this.element = document.createElement("div");
    this.audio = new Audio("./audio/LaserShot.wav");
}
```

And in upper class Spaceship I call it every time I shot pressing space:

```
executeShot() {
    const bullet = new Bullet(this.getCurrentPosition(), this.element.offsetTop, this.area);
    bullet.init();
    this.bullets.push(bullet);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more info, like does multiple Audio need to play at the same time or not?

Comment: Yes they are creating all paraller, you can shot while enemies are respawning and they also has new Audio() in their constructor

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works great in all scenario, but you can try the following code, and see if it works.

```html
<button class="btn">Click</button>
```

```js
class AudioService {
    constructor(initialsetup = 1) {
        this._audios = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < initialsetup; i++) {
            this._audios.push(new Audio());
        }
    }

    /**
     * use to get available audio
     */
    _getAudioElemToPlay() {
        const audios = this._audios.filter(audio => {
            // if the audio is empty, without a valid url or if the audio is ended
            // TODO: not sure if these attributes are more than enough
            return !audio.duration || audio.ended;
        });
        console.log('audios', audios);
        if (audios.length == 0) {
            const audio = new Audio();
            this._audios.push(audio);
            return audio;
        }
        return audios[0];
    }

    playAudio(url) {
        const player = this._getAudioElemToPlay();
        player.src = url;
        player.load();
        player.play();
    }
}

const audioService = new AudioService();

let index = 0;
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    index++;
    const audioList = new Array(12).fill(0).map((value, index) => {
        return `https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-${index}.mp3`;
    });
    audioService.playAudio(audioList[index % audioList.length]);
})
```

Here is the link to run the above code, https://codepen.io/hphchan/pen/xxqbezb.
You may also change the audio to other audio as you like.

---

My main idea to solve the issue, is by reusing the audio element created, by having an array to store it, and reuse the element once it finish playing.
Of course, for the demo, I am playing the audio by using a click button. But definitely, you can plug it into your game.

Hope the solution may help you. In case there are any cases not covering, as I have not much exposure to this area, it would be nice if you can post your modified solution here, so we can all learn together.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Web Audio API? If it works for you, a single [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) can hold the audio data in memory for a given cue, and you can play it multiple times by spawning `AudioBufferSourceNode` objects. If you have many different sounds playing, this might not be much help, but if you are reusing sounds continuously (many laser shots), this could a big help. Another benefit is that this way of playing sounds is pretty low latency.

I just used this for the first time, getting it to work yesterday. But I'm loading it with raw PCM data (floats ranging from -1 to 1). There is surely a way to load this or an equivalent in-memory structure with a wav, but I'm too new to the API to know yet how to do this.